# Are multiple JOINs unavailable when using ADODB to query an Excel file in a VBA procedure?

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

I have 3 sheets with data formatted as tables. The sheets names are "Riesgos", "Eventos" and "EventosRiesgos".

EventosRiesgo has information relating events and risks (many to many relationship).

I'm trying to get all the risks from Riesgos, but also the events related to the risks from (. I'm using ADODB to query the sheets as database tables and using the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [Riesgos$] r
LEFT JOIN [EventosRiesgos$] er ON r.[Id]=er.[Id Riesgo]
LEFT JOIN [Eventos$] e ON er.[Id Evento]=e.[Id]
```

But i get an error, it's in Spanish but a rough translation would be: Syntax error (missing operator) in expression "r.[Id]=er.[Id Riesgo] LEFT JOIN [Eventos$] e ON er.[Id Evento]=e.[Id]"

When I run the query only using the first 2 lines (only one join) everything works as expected. My question is: Why is the query not working when I use the two JOINs?

Can anyone help me, at least to find documentation on the use of ADODB to query Excel sheets?

Comment: Another related questio: Are FULL JOINs supported on ADODB?

Comment: You can use pretty nearly anything from these : [Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx) --
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx) -- 
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Apparently FULL JOINs are **not** supported, can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>Access</strike> Jet/ADODB/ACE likes brackets with multiple tables

```
SELECT  * FROM ( [Riesgos$] r
LEFT JOIN [EventosRiesgos$] er ON r.[Id]=er.[Id Riesgo] )
LEFT JOIN [Eventos$] e ON er.[Id Evento]=e.[Id]
```

The only difference is brackets around the `[riesgos$] r ....  er.[Id Riesggo]`

Comment: It seems that the maximum number of left joins is 8, can somebody confirm / explain this ?

Comment: @stef, [2007](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx) 16, [2010](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) 16, but both say may be less if the query includes multivalued lookup fields.