# Query format issue in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need ti run following query in access DB. What would be the changes needs to do.
Because it gives an syntax error

```
SELECT t1.col11,  t3.col32,  t2.col22,  t2.col23
FROM t1,  t2,  t3
WHERE t1.col11 = t3.col31
AND t3.col32 = t2.col21 (+)
```

I tried below but still gives a syntax error

```
SELECT t1.col11,  t3.col32,  t2.col22,  t2.col23
FROM t1, t3 left outer join t2 ON t1.col11 = t3.col31
WHERE t1.col11 = t3.col31
```

Appreciate your help

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: you are joining t3 with t2, but the join condition is t1,t3?

Comment: If you are running this in VBA, please include the code.   Otherwise you may not get helpful responses.  (While you are at it, restore the VBA tag which I removed, thinking it did not apply.)

Comment: Basic trouble shooting:  Try simplified versions of the query until you find one that runs.  Then work up to the final version.

Answer (score 0):

by pasting your original SQL into the Access query window, it returned this:

```
SELECT   t1.col11, t3.col32, t2.col22, t2.col23
FROM     (t1 INNER JOIN
         t3 ON t1.col11 = t3.col31) INNER JOIN
         t2 ON t3.col32 = t2.col21
```

Access is fairly good at translating basic SQL like this - you just have to watch for commands it doesn't understand

Comment: @HansUp, yeah - [**I**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322576/are-multiple-joins-unavailable-when-using-adodb-to-query-an-excel-file-in-a-vba/12323096#12323096) definitely should have known that. fixed

Comment: How can we translate sql script directly by just copy paste. It didn't work for me

Comment: The (+) sign after t2.col21 appears to be the old Oracle pre-ansi outer join syntax, where the (+) was on the deficient side of the join, so your join from t3 to t2 should be a "LEFT JOIN".