# Why I can not double join query in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am making Excel so that I can use it like a DB.
(When I press Select button, My Select statement is executed.)

[image]

However, an error occurs when I use a double join statement.
Please review my code and tell me about my problem.

---------------- My Visual Basic code -----------------------------------

```
Sub mySelect()
    Dim myQuery As String
     
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
    
    'Delete all previously searched
    ActiveSheet.Range("B9").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    
    DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
     
    'HDR=Yes --> First row of data sheet is used as field name
    sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
     
    conn.Open sconnect
    myQuery = Cells(3, 2).Value
    mrs.Open myQuery, conn
    
    'print to screen
    ActiveSheet.Range("B9").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    
    'close DB recordset
    mrs.Close
    'close DB Connection
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

------------------ my Query ---------------------------------

```
SELECT req.IssueNo, req.RequestMemo FROM [IssueBasicInfo$] info

Left Join [IssueRequest$] req ON info.IssueNo = req.IssueNo

Left Join [IssueFile$] file On info.IssueNo = file.IssueNo
```

------------------ DB Structure -----------------------------

IssueBasicInfo

[image]

IssueFile

[image]

IssueRequest

[image]

Comment: When I Use single Join Query, It is not happen any problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322576/are-multiple-joins-unavailable-when-using-adodb-to-query-an-excel-file-in-a-vba

Answer (score 0):

This query will produce duplicate rows for req, and this is the problem. You're right that if you remove second join everything is OK. Try to change sql select to:

SELECT DISTINCT req.IssueNo, req.RequestMemo FROM [IssueBasicInfo$] info

Left Join [IssueRequest$] req ON info.IssueNo = req.IssueNo

Left Join [IssueFile$] file On info.IssueNo = file.IssueNo